# How to create user defined datatypes in Apache Jena?

Tags: jena, user-defined-data-types

I'm creating an ontology using Apache Jena. However, I can't find a way of creating custom datatypes as in the following example: 
     'has value' some xsd:float[>= 0.0f , <= 15.0f].

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Are you using jena `OntModel`, and the question is about how to create a named data range with a given constraint in an ontological graph ? Or you want some builtin facility to create an instance of `org.apache.jena.datatypes.RDFDatatype` with desired limitations to use while inference?

Comment: @ssz Yes, I'm using OntModel and I'd like to create a named data range with the constrain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems what you need is [DatatypeRestriction](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Datatype_Restrictions) with two facet restrictions: `xsd:minInclusive` and `xsd:maxInclusive`.
It is OWL2 constructions.

`org.apache.jena.ontology.OntModel` does not support OWL2, only OWL1.1 partially (see [documentation](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/)), and, therefore, there are no builtin methods for creating such data-ranges (there is only `DataOneOf` data range expression, see `OntModel#createDataRange(RDFList)`).

So you have to create a desired datatype manually, triple by triple, using the general `org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Model` interface.
In RDF, it would look like this:

```
_:x rdf:type rdfs:Datatype.
_:x owl:onDatatype DN.
_:x owl:withRestrictions (_:x1 ... _:xn).
```

See also [owl2-quick-guide](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-quick-reference/#Data_Ranges).

Or, to build such an ontology, you can use some external utilities or APIs. 
For example, in [ONT-API](https://github.com/owlcs/ont-api) (**v. 2.x.x**) the following snippet

```
    String ns = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54131709#";
    OntModel m = OntModelFactory.createModel()
            .setNsPrefixes(OntModelFactory.STANDARD).setNsPrefix("q", ns);
    OntDataRange.Named floatDT = m.getDatatype(XSD.xfloat);
    OntFacetRestriction min = m.createFacetRestriction(OntFacetRestriction.MinInclusive.class,
            floatDT.createLiteral("0.0"));
    OntFacetRestriction max = m.createFacetRestriction(OntFacetRestriction.MaxInclusive.class,
            floatDT.createLiteral("15.0"));
    OntDataRange.Named myDT = m.createDatatype(ns + "MyDatatype");
    myDT.addEquivalentClass(m.createDataRestriction(floatDT, min, max));
    m.createResource().addProperty(m.createDataProperty(ns + "someProperty"),
            myDT.createLiteral("2.2"));
    m.write(System.out, "ttl");
```

will produce the following ontology:

```
@prefix q:     <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54131709#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

[ q:someProperty  "2.2"^^q:MyDatatype ] .

q:MyDatatype  a              rdfs:Datatype ;
        owl:equivalentClass  [ a                     rdfs:Datatype ;
                               owl:onDatatype        xsd:float ;
                               owl:withRestrictions  ( [ xsd:minInclusive  "0.0"^^xsd:float ]
                                                       [ xsd:maxInclusive  "15.0"^^xsd:float ]
                                                     )
                             ] .

q:someProperty  a  owl:DatatypeProperty .
```